# How to use var expression that define in an event in other events?

Tags: c#, linq

Hi i made a question database.in a click event i randomly take some rows and store them in `randomselectedQuestion` varaiable.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var allSelectedQuestion =   glnq.PSelectAllQuestion(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue)); 

  Random face = new Random();
 var randomselectedQuestion = allSelectedQuestion.OrderBy(c =>face.Next()).Select(c=>c).Take(Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToList();
}
```

how can i use randomselectedQuestion in otherevents to access rows and columns data. i store it in list<> but i cant access columns.
thank u.

Comment: Replace var with actual type plus make this variable shared between methods.

Comment: Declare redomselectedQuestion in global space instead as a local variable.  You can still use 'var', Wiktor is wrong.

Comment: How can i define it outside event?? i cant use var there..in public class

Comment: @jdweng You cannot use var at class scope.

Comment: @jdweng: class members can't be declared with var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define that variable outside `button1_Click` handler scope like

```
IEnumerable<allSelectedQuestionType> randomselectedQuestion = null;
```

and in your method `button1_click`:

```
 this.randomselectedQuestion = allSelectedQuestion.OrderBy(c =>face.Next()).Select(c=>c).Take(Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToList();
```